# sslv3 alert handshake failure with LWP::UserAgent

Tags: perl, https, handshake, lwp-useragent, sslv3

I'm trying to make an https request using `LWP::UserAgent`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $login_url = 'https://www.icscards.nl/abnamrogb/login/login';
my $ssl_options = { SSL_version => 'tlsv1', verify_hostname => 0 };
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => $ssl_options);
$browser->cookie_jar( {} );

my $response = $browser->get($login_url);
print $response->decoded_content;
```

and get the following error message:

```
Can't connect to www.icscards.nl:443

LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.
```

Changing the URL to e.g. `https://www.google.com/` works fine, but not the URL I want to fetch.

Worth noting: I get the same error when making a request to this URL with python.

Comment: Your code snipet just works and prints the page content without any error. Using: macOS Sierra, (darwin 16.7), LWP::UserAgent: 6.26, Mozilla::CA: 20160104, IO::Socket::SSL: 2.052

Comment: Also had lwp https issues and permanently switched to mojo::useragent. RIP lwp. `\o/`

Answer (score 3):

> ... alert handshake failure at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.

It looks like you are using MacOS and and older version of Perl. Based on this I assume that your underlying OpenSSL version is still 0.9.8, because this ancient version of OpenSSL is the one which got shipped with MacOS. You can verify my assumption by calling

```
perl -MNet::SSLeay -E 'say Net::SSLeay::SSLeay_version(0)
```

If this reports version 0.9.8 my assumption is right. If this report 1.0.0 I'm wrong but the following still applies. If it reports 1.0.1 or even better the following explanation does not apply.

OpenSSL 0.9.8 does not support ECDHE ciphers as can be also seen at [report from SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=OpenSSL&version=0.9.8y&key=27). Only, this server requires ECDHE ciphers as can be seen from [this report by SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.icscards.nl). Thus, there is no common cipher between client and server which means that the TLS handshake fails.

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right, I have OpenSSL 0.9.8zg. Any tips on how to upgrade it or make perl / python use a newer version?

Comment: @JureMerhar: there are several information online on how to use homebrew to install a new OpenSSL and how to create a Python installation using this OpenSSL. For Perl you only need to rebuild Net::SSLeay using this new OpenSSL instead of rebuilding all of Perl but there are instructions about this online too.